# Is there a way to style all divs in a css class?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am extremely new to css/frontend and I was wondering if there was any way to style all subsequent html elements within a css class.

For example all the div within styles.error.

I am using Modules with react and am confused about why this code below doesn't style the entire div element.

[Error.module.css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6D7f.png)

[error.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fX0D1.png)

[Page view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KewRm.png)

I expected to see the div element to be coloured in

Comment: Do not post text in images, please edit your question to includ the text/code/errors itself.

Comment: Also your CSS selector targets `.error div`, which means all `div`s inside a parent element that has class `error`. Look at your HTML, you have no divs inside your error div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things here you can notice:

- Recheck your CSS selectors, be careful all space and order of your class name & tag name. As according to your JSX, you don't have any div inside class `.error`. It should be `div.error` instead of `.error div`.
- Modules CSS in React is only applied inside a single file where it is imported, so if you need a more global solution to style all errors in all pages, you can consider to use normal CSS files (e.g. `styles.css` or `error.css`, whatever name it is), and then import those global CSS files in you **`index.js`**.

Hope this can help!